# Should access to an Online/Crowd-Sourced Regulatory Impact Analysis (RIA) site be fully open?

Tags: web-forums, legal, community-organizing

I am attempting to create an online Regulatory Impact Analysis (RIA) web site/forum. The site/forum aims to assess the costs and benefits of state and local level legislation through crowd sourcing. The goal of the project is to better educate prospective voters on the costs and benefits of upcoming legislation. The initial phase of the project aims to provide voters with a basic, yet easily digestible set of numeric values to quantify the costs and benefits of upcoming legislation.

Through crowd sourcing, the hope is that these valuations can occur in a transparent and open manner. If these valuations are erroneous or misleading, members of the community can debate and correct any invalid valuations. Another hope is that through crowd sourcing, these valuations can occur more quickly than traditional RIA’s. This is important, as RIA’s can sometimes take months if not years to complete and are generally only performed on large/far-reaching pieces of legislation.

**Should membership be open to everyone and anyone?**

**My thoughts on 'yes':** With a greater number of members, the knowledge base and speed at which RIA’s can be completed would increase.

**My thoughts on 'no':** Influence from external parties/non-voters could skew the RIA, resulting in RIA which is beneficial to non-voters. For example, let us say California was voting on legislation to ban meat from slaughterhouses that don't meet standards none of the major slaughterhouses in California meet. Instead, slaughterhouses in another state (e.g., Texas) or another country (e.g., Uruguay) meet the new criteria. People from Texas, Uruguay, etc., could skew the RIA in favor of the legislation. This would ultimately be to the benefit of Texas, Uruguay, etc., both of which do not consist of California voters.

Answer (score 1):

The post was closed down because its too political.  Very sad.

Regulatory Impact Analysis (RIA)

Your talking Politics in RIA and your only Goal.

1. Your First and only stated goal is to better educate perspective voters on the costs and benefits of upcoming legislation. That is also an honorable goal.
2. you state the valuations could occur in a transparent and open manner. Also an honorable goal.
3. Crowd sourcing SHOULD be a final objective. It seems to me that currency at the Local and State level is already over Over Tapped and Taxed.  Therefor you will not get a warm reception to the idea.
4. The RIA should be part of any Governments Budget.  If its not, the Governments corrupt.  That simple.

A) Crowd sourcing should be your GOAL. Perform the Cost Benefits.  That could be your Analysis.  That should be the Governments job. But take it on as your own work.  But don't expect a rewards for your WORK.

Your into money, politics and Special interests.  All corrupting elements.

Keep your head up...  keep going.

These are my feedback. You do as you believe in.

Comment: Hey Joseph, welcome to Community Build Stack Exchange.  Could you clarify how your post answers the question?  You make some interesting observations about the idea, but the OP was specifically asking about whether or not such an effort shold be open to everyone or just specific people.  This post doesn't seem to answer that question.

Stack Exchange is a Q/A community rather than a message board, so posts that are not answers to the question will have to be removed to keep answers easily discoverable.